# I missed the Added-Effect Materia, where can I find another?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I must of overlooked it in the Cave of Gi and was wondering where I could possibly pick up an Added-Effect materia?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! I edited your question's title a bit and removed the name of the game from the beginning. You don't need to put the game name there, since as long as your question is properly tagged [it will be added to the title automatically](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/why-is-the-first-tag-sometimes-in-the-title-tag-of-some-questions).

Answer (score 3):

The Cave of Gi on Disk One is the only place to get the Added Effect materia.  If you miss it, sold it, or otherwise got rid of it, there is no way to get another.

See [here](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Support_Materia#Added_Effect) for more information.

There are [unsupported rumors](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/1169/t252553-another-way-to-get-added-effect-materia/) that you are able to dig one up in Bone Village at a later time, but I've never seen conclusive evidence that that's the case.  No reputable sources on the web support that claim.

Comment: Based on everything I've ever read or experienced with FF7 and bone village, [this map](http://www.shillatime.org/bonevillage.jpg) appears to be accurate. As such, added-effect is not available there. If you miss it, you're out of luck.